# Z-shape with crossing line

Tags: geometry

Considering the following picture, in which the top and bottom line segments of the Z shape are parallel, and the dashed line crosses top and bottom segments of Z at the midpoint:

[image: Z-Shape Landmark]

Find the length of $X_2$ segment as a function of $L_1$, $L_2$, and $W$.

[This reference](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejohannb/Papers/pos96rep.pdf) states that $X_2=W\left(\frac{L_1}{L_1+L_2} - \frac{1}{2}\right)$. However, I failed to follow why this is true.

So my question is: How to derive this equation for $X_2$? I tried to work it backwards, by rearranging the equation, but I arrived at no conclusion.

Background:
I came across this Z-shaped landmark-based localization method, which tried to localize an unmanned (autonomous) dump truck on the way (For details, refer to [http://www-personal.umich.edu/~johannb/Papers/pos96rep.pdf](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejohannb/Papers/pos96rep.pdf), Section 7.3.3, Pg. 179).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Using the intercept theorem on the parallel lines $AB$ and $CD$, and on the parallel lines $BC$ and $EF$, we obtain

$$\frac{L_1}{L_1+L_2} = \frac{|P_1P_2|}{|P_1P_3|} = \frac{|AP_2|}{|AC|} = \frac{|AE|}{|AB|} = \frac{|AE|}{W} = \frac{X_2 + \frac W2}{W} = \frac{X_2}{W} + \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks, @Magma ! This actually answers my question, but can you please add where can I find proof of this result?

Comment: My answer *is* a proof of the result. What more would you like to know?

Comment: Sorry, I meant a proof of the theorem.

Comment: Of the intercept theorem? It's an elementary theorem of geometry everyone knows, you could probably find a proof in Euclid's Elements if you bothered to look. You can prove it yourself by using the fact that triangles with three common angles are similar.